# Postgres sort vs. Ruby on Rails Sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql, sorting

Lately we had to support our web app with 'pagination'

of 2 different Models (Customers, Inquiries) from our DB.

---

Let's assume our page size is 5,

and we're sorting 'First Name'.

Thus all of our following 'sort' operations will sort by first_name

---

**Our process uses *Sort* 3 times in :**

1. DB sort - Customers model. DB returns 5 records.
2. DB sort - Inquiries model. DB returns 5 records.
3. store all the above records in an array.
4. Ruby sort (Using *sort!* method) - Sorting the above 10 records by the FirstName field.
5. Render the first 5 records to the client (after the sort).

**Our problem:**

It seems the Postgres sorting and Ruby sorting for strings are quite different.

For example, Postgres and Ruby sorts the following words differently.

1. w1 = 'customer 1'
2. w2 = 'customer - hello'

**Sorting results:**

Postgres: w1, w2

Ruby: w2, w1 (the opposite).

It lies in the face Ruby comparator for Digit and Dash(-) character is the opposite to Postgres.

---

Our problem lies only within sorting of 'Strings'.

Sorting by Date / Integer are acting the same (and thank God it is).

Does anyone knows if it's possible to override / configure the sorting of Ruby?
Thus our expected results of the Array sort would follow the configuration of Postgres sort.

Comment: Sort takes a block, you can sort however you want.

Comment: There is no such thing as “Postgres sort.” How postgres sorts hardly depends on collations set on specific tables/columns.

Comment: PostgreSQL uses operating system collations for sorting. What do you get for `SHOW lc_collate;` in your database? That's the ordering you need.

Comment: @mudasobwa: did you mean "hardly depends" or "depends very much"? :)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe - I used *SHOW lc_collate* and I got "en_US.UTF-8". Can I set **Ruby** sort operation to sort similar to postgres?

Comment: @mudasobwa - Thanks, I was searching for this without knowing what i'm looking for.. Can I use what Laurentz guide me to find (the collation) and set the ruby to act the same?

Comment: @DaveNewton - thanks for your response, but I Didn't understand it. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I always do this stupid mistake, thanks, of course I meant “depends very much.”

Comment: @mudasobwa: yeah, best not to make this mistake in a weekly progress report or something. "I was hardly working this week" :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Unfortunately this particular mistake wins all my fights against it. I do it everywhere. Once I had a slide saying “We hardly did our best” in front of 100+ clients audience.

Comment: My favorite is "I'm fed up" when "I'm full" (e.g., I can't eat any more) is meant: being "fed up" means "intensely frustrated and can't take it any more" in American English. Language is fun! @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @DaveNewton,
It seems Postgres ignore the Dash character.
Found it on [this refernce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955386/postgresql-ignores-dashes-when-ordering).
In ASCII - 'dash' decimal value is 45, and '2' decimal value is 50.
Therefor "aa -a" is should appear before "aa 2a" in the sort result, but it's the opposite.
Meanwhile in Ruby, the 'dash' comes before the '2' causes a reversed order and this is why we had our problem.
We used convert_to('column_name', 'SQL_ASCII') function in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a custom sort. This can be achieved by creating a custom method to compare 2 characters in order to remplace the default `<=>` one used by the `sort` method.

You can implement an comparison operation between strings that works as you wish (mine might not be the better one, but at least it inverts the comparison between dash and digits as you wished).

Here is my example of a custom comparison method :

```
def custom_compare(s1, s2)
  s1_array = s1.split("")
  s2_array = s2.split("")
  s1_array.each_with_index do |c1, i|
    c2 = s2_array[i]
    if c1 != c2
      if(c1 == "-" && c2 =~ /\d/ || c2 == "-" && c1 =~ /\d/)
        return c1 == "-" ? 1 : -1
      end
      return c1 <=> c2
    end
  end
  return 0
end
```

Then use it in a ruby sort :

```
["customer - hello", "customer 1"].sort!{|a, b| custom_compare(a, b)}
# => ["customer 1", "customer - hello"]
```

Comment: I'm using custom sort already. The sort by Name is actually sort by: first_name, last_name and the corresponding sorting in Ruby is custom compare that sorts by first_name, last_name again.

The problem is that the Ruby sort operation on strings act differently than the PostgresDB. And I can't override each comparison for every 2 chars..

Comment: yes, so you should break down the `sort` to its comparison operation, and change it. I've updated my answer with a `custom_compare` method where I tried to invert the comparison between a dash and an integer

Comment: It's a lot of computing for something I think that already exist. and I means to what others mention that called "collations for sorting". Using your way, to guarantee same behaviour in Ruby and in my DB, I will need to override each comparison between every 2 characters. at most N choose 2 overrides ...

Comment: If it already exist, it would be something equivalent. Native methods are not more efficient than the ones you craft yourself. I don't say that my `custom_compare` is the one, I say you should build yours.